# Doctrine TargetEntity on another Entity Manager

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

I have two entity managers, one table from one entity manager has to be mapped to another entity on another entity manager.

I've succeeded to configure both entity managers and both connections. But it seems that entity managers can't talk together.
I mean, they can't be related or mapped together.
No Cross-database possible with doctrine?

For this case, both databases are on SQLite, but it could be any.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Vote;

use App\Entity\Main\Movie;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(schema="Vote", name="vote")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=VoteRepository::class)
 */
class Vote
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $note;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=App\Entity\Main\Movie::class, inversedBy="votes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $idMovie;
```

And the other:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Main;

use App\Entity\Vote\Vote;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(schema="Main", name="movie")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MovieRepository::class)
 */
class Movie
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Vote::class, mappedBy="idMovie", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $votes;
```

Comment: The response is no. No cross entity manager and no cross database.